# MariaDB galera cluster wsrep GTID numbering after update from 10.5.16 to higher versions

Tags: mariadb, upgrade, gtid, wsrep

I had a fully functional MariaDB 10.5.16 with a Galera cluster (26.4.11). There were 3 nodes, and the GTID was set up and functioning properly, with each server having identical settings, including server_id = 1, and wsrep_gtid_domain_id=11.

After upgrading to version 10.5.19 of Galera cluster (26.4.14), the GTID numbering stopped working predictably. I noticed the problem when restoring one of the nodes using SST. The GTID began producing numbers with local GTIDs, or the GTID diverged from the other servers.

After updating mariaDB to higher versions, I was unable to sync the GTID in the Galera cluster. I even tried restarting the new Galera cluster, followed by SST on the joining nodes, changing the ID numbers, etc. But nothing worked. I assumed it could be a bug, but after going through all the Mariadb versions up to 10.11.2, there appears to be some new functionality in Galera GTID numbering that doesn't make sense to me.

Have you encountered a similar problem? Is there any documentation on the new behavior of Galera GTID numbering and syncing? I haven't found any information on it.